# I deleted ubuntu and now GRUB doesn't boot into windows anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I am aware that if you just delete ubuntu, your pc isn't going to work anymore. I followed this guide on how to repair the MBR but it won't work so now I'm doomed. it said to do:

-bootrec /fixmbr 
-boorrec /fixboot

When I boot up I get the "Minimal Bash-Like line editing is supported, For the first word...."

I can't factory reset with a windows DVD because there's no recovery partition (apparently) .

I don't care if I lose any files at all, I just want my pc working again preferably with windows but ubuntu could work to.

Possible extra info: I was on Windows 8.1 and ubuntu 14.04 (I think, possibly 14.10) Grub version 2.02 beta2-9

Please help me, I know I messed up.

Comment: The bootec commands are Windows command line commands not Linux terminal commands. You have to run those from your Windows repair console in your Windows repair flash drive. You did make one of those as recommended when you first booted Windows? If not you may be able to use Boot-Repair if installed in BIOS mode.  If in UEFI mode, just go into UEFI boot menu and choose Windows. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair If Windows 8 was pre-installed then it is UEFI mode.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different PC , install [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net) and create a bootable image of your favourite OS using USB and install it

Comment: I already have a DVD that's used to help with problems and install windows for the first time. So is that the same as creating a bootable image, just installing another windows on top of everything?

Comment: Use live CD to delete everything through terminal using this - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-disk-format/
And then install Ubuntu / Windows

Answer (score 0):

Boot to your original Windows disk, when it loads find an option like "Repair your computer", find a way to get in CMD and type:

```
bootrec.exe /fixboot

bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

Then exit and boot the PC up normally and you should be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I sorted it withput repair disk:

Download Puppy linux puppylinux.org

Load it on ypur USB using Unetbootin
Boot it and in menu start find System -> Grub4DOS boot loader

In a dialog box choose your hard drive with windows on it and select 'Search ony within this device' option. Click OK

There will be confirmation regarding name of drive you want to use (e.g. Sda)

When search is done choose to edit menu.lst

In that file change timeout from 10 to 0 ( unless you have some other operating systems you want to use).

Save this menu.lst file, close it.

Press ok on the final grub setting window.

Restart your compuwell).ter (you can remove usb as well).

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a Windows CD/USB and run:

```
BCDBoot c:\Windows
```

where c: is the drive Windows is installed.

If you get "Failure when attempting to copy boot files" error. Start `diskpart`

```
list volume
```

After this, it will list your hard drives. Select the one your OS is on.

- `select volume 0` (0 for first hard drive etc.)
- `list partition`
- `select partition 0` (select EFI partition, usually first partition. So 0. EFI partition should be the one no letter assigned to it)
- `assign letter=Z` (or some other letter)
- `exit` (exit diskpart)

Now you can copy those files by:

```
BCDBoot c:\Windows /s z: /f UEFI
```

[source](http://www.qliktips.com/2012/11/fix-windows-8-boot-issue.html)

Answer (score 0):

REboot and press your pc's boot key - on mine is f12. Then select boot windows rather than boot Ubuntu. Save and restart to windows. Then download and install EasyBCD and recreate/repair the boot files on the BCD BAckup Rapir tab. Delte partitions afterwards if need be.

Comment: This was a year ago lol