# I deleted Ubuntu's partition on my hard drive now I get gnu grub version 2.02 on boot

Tags: grub2

I wanted to get rid of Ubuntu, but, like an idiot, I just deleted its volume on my hard drive. Now, when I boot up, I get a gnu grub command line screen. How can I get past and fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I deleted ubuntu and now GRUB doesn't boot into windows anymore](http://askubuntu.com/questions/610535/i-deleted-ubuntu-and-now-grub-doesnt-boot-into-windows-anymore)

Comment: If UEFI: Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu

Answer (score 0):

> Boot to your original Windows disk, when it loads find an option like
>   "Repair your computer", find a way to get in CMD and type:
>
> ```
> bootrec.exe /fixboot
>
> bootrec.exe /fixmbr
> ```
>
> Then exit and boot the PC up normally and you should be sorted.

https://askubuntu.com/a/610864

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what version of windows you are using. It looks like windows 7 and higher is a bit more involved. Just in case this is the case with your setup, I have found a helpful site for repairing windows 8 boot loader. You will however, need a bootable USB drive. 
http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-fix-windows-8-mbr-master-boot-record/

If that does not work for you, you can do a search for restoring Windows 8 EFI bootloader or Windows 8 fix MBR.

However, after going to the command prompt through the windows recovery tool. you will probably just need to run. 
bootrec.exe /fixmbr

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear what you want. If what you want is to remove GRUB, so that when the computer boots, you will no longer see the GRUB screen, do this:

Start Ubuntu or any other Linux system (that comes with sudo preinstalled) from another media than your harddrive. For instance you could use a plain Ubuntu installation USB. This comes with a live Ubuntu desktop you can try (start it up and press 'Try Ubuntu')

From this system, open up a terminal (if using Ubuntu, press ctrl+alt+t)

First, find the 'id' of your harddrive. If you type in:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

You will get a list of harddrives and what partitions they contain. All the harddrives will have names like /dev/sdx or /dev/hdx (where x is a letter)

In the terminal, run the following command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=446 count=1
```

(where sdx is 'id' of the harddrive (referred to as the name of the harddrive above)

If prompted for a password when running the command, type in the sudo password. This should be blank or ubuntu if using the ubuntu live system.

The above command will replace GRUB on your harddrive with zeros.